# Single Page Web Apps. Many requests made at application startup OK?

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, backbone.js, single-page-application

I have been working on a Single Page Web App (SPA) for some time. Frontend uses BackboneJS/Marionette, Backend is Java Spring `:(`. But what I find possibly slow is at application start, many requests are made to different API end points to populate data for various parts of the application. I think this is slow? Though they are AJAX requests and therefore done asynchronously? Whats the best practice? At first I was thinking I somehow combine everything into 1 huge request, but not sure if thats a very good idea. Also code examples are nice.

Comment: Depending of your application you could use caching with localstorage and display cached information on startup and refresh information in background. While it doesn't load the latest data fast, it at least load some data fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know what should be there on page load, all this data should really be served along with your default html and your objects initialized with it. I use AMD so I would do it like,

```
<script data-main="app" src="/lib/require.js"></script>
<script>
define('load', function(){return {
    mymodel : <c:out value="${mymodel}" default="{}" />,
        ...
};});
</script>
```

app.js:

```
require([ 'MyModel', 'load'], function(MyModel, load) {
  var myModel = new MyModel(load.mymodel);
   ...
})
```

Comment: whats `<c:out value="${mymodel}" default="{}" />`? Some server side template tag? Then if multiple files require the `load` file, it will only download it once I believe?

Comment: @JiewMeng Yes server side template. The point is that the HTML that is sent **should contain all the information in it already** so that on initial load no callbacks are needed. Later if you need to update your data you can just call call `myModel.fetch()` and use AJAX as normal. Load isn't a file, it is a module defined on page load. You can send it however you want though, I just showed one way.

Answer (score 0):

One huge request isn't a bad idea.  You may desire this functionality anyway for synchronization purposes.

Putting any dynamic content into the HTML prevents you from caching the front end code. You won't be able to deploy your front end statically - packaged into a mobile app, for example.  It may also slow down initial render time, although the app will take slightly longer to load as a whole due to requiring two requests instead of one.